# Por que meu array não é ordenado? (Bubble Sort)

Tags: c, array

Eu alimentei o array com o input do usuário, porém o algoritmo não da o output de maneira ordenada, o que eu fiz de errado?

```
    int main()
    {

// variáveis
        int vetor[5] = {0};
        int aux, i=0, j=0;
            printf("Entre com  numeros\n\n");

// input    
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                scanf("%i", & vetor[i]);
            }

//Ordenação    
           for(i=0;i<5;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<(5-1);j++){
                    if(vetor[j] > vetor[j++]){
                        aux = vetor[j];
                        vetor[j] = vetor[j++];
                        vetor[j++] = aux;
                    }
                }

            }

//Output  
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                printf("%i\t",vetor[i]);
            }


        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `if` que tem na parte da ordenação está a utilizar `j++` para aceder ao elemento seguinte:

```
if(vetor[j] > vetor[j++]){
//                    ^--
   aux = vetor[j];
   vetor[j] = vetor[j++];
//                    ^--
   vetor[j++] = aux;
//         ^--
}
```

Isto modifica o valor de `j` permanentemente. Por isso está a aumentar o `j` varias vezes por cada iteração, na verdade ou 2 vezes ou 4 vezes, dependendo se entra ou não dentro do `if`. O correto é aceder ao próximo sem modificar o `j` fazendo `j + 1`:

```
//Ordenação
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(j=0;j<(5-1);j++){
        if(vetor[j] > vetor[j+1]){
            aux = vetor[j];
            vetor[j] = vetor[j+1];
            vetor[j+1] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

[Código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/VkjjdN)

Talvez seja boa ideia também rever um pouco como funciona o operador `++` e `--` tanto em pré como em pós incremento.